# Unified Expression Language, method call list argument

Tags: java, collections, el

i have next method:

```
public int countEvents(List<EventTypeEnum> eventTypes)
```

now how to call this method from unified EL ?

With non collection enum arguments works fine but not with collection

Tried

```
${countEvents("ALERT")}
${countEvents(["ALERT"])}
```

both crashes

Answer (score 0):

If the values are fixed, you might just do this:

```
public int countEvents(List<EventTypeEnum> eventTypes) { ... }
public int countAlerts() { 
    return countEvents(Arrays.asList(EventTypeEnum.ALERT)); 
}

${countAlerts()}
```

This is usually the simplest and clearest solution.

Comment: I need to use collection elements not just collection size

Answer (score 0):

Enums could be treated as strings in jstl. But there is no direct way by which you could create a list in jstl. You need to have a list of evenTypes in scope, say `${eventTypes}`, which is a `List<EventTypeEnum>` then you could directly the method in you bean like `${bean.countEvents(eventTypes)}`.

However from your code i presume you need to create this on the fly. In that case you'll have to rely on standard jsp. Say you have an enum

```
public enum EventTypeEnum {
    ALERT, ONCLICK, ONBLUR
}
```

And a pojo which has the count method like

```
import java.util.List;

public class CountBean {

    public int countEvents(List<EventTypeEnum> eventTypes){
        return eventTypes.size();
    }

}
```

So if you have an instance of `CountBean` in scope, say `${myBean}` then in you jsp you could do like

```
<jsp:useBean id="events" class="java.util.ArrayList"> 
  <% 
    events.add("ALERT");
    events.add("ONCLICK");
  %>
</jsp:useBean>

Length : <c:out value="${myBean.countEvents(events)}"/>
```

This would work fine. If you dont want to use `<jsp:useBean>` approach you could use MicroNova YUZU tags. It is an open-source EL-based JSP tag libary designed to augment JSTL. More details could be found on  http://www.micronova.com/yuzu.jsp.

If you dont want to create bean instances to invoke this method and wish to use it as static you could create custom jstl methods as explained [here](http://www.noppanit.com/how-to-create-a-custom-function-for-jstl/) or [here](http://balusc.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/hidden-features-of-jspservlet.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I use expression language in Activiti tasks and there is available only EL